# How to Show a Value One Time in Loop

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I'm working on a cart in a website but its showing total price according to the products. If add three products then the total price will show three times, and if I add two products into the cart, then it shows two times.

**cart.blade.php**

```php
<table>
    <tr class="table-row">
        <?php $total_amount = 0; ?>
        @foreach($userCart as $cart)
            <td class="column-1">
                <div class="cart-img-product b-rad-4 o-f-hidden">
                    <img src="{{ asset('images/backend_images/products/small/'.$cart->image) }}" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="column-2">{{ $cart->product_name }}</td>
            <td class="column-3">PKR: {{ $cart->price }}</td>
            <td class="column-4">
                <div class="flex-w bo5 of-hidden w-size17">
                    <a class="cart_quantity_up color1 flex-c-m size7 bg8 eff2"
                       href="{{ url('/cart/update-quantity/'.$cart->id.'/1') }}">+</a>
                    <input class="size8 m-text18 t-center num-product" type="number" name="quantity"
                           value="{{ $cart->quantity }}">
                    @if($cart->quantity>1)
                        <a class="cart_quantity_down color1 flex-c-m size7 bg8 eff2"
                           href="{{ url('/cart/update-quantity/'.$cart->id.'/-1') }}">-</a>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="column-5">PKR: {{ $cart->price }}</td>
            <td class="column-6"><a href="{{ url('/cart/delete-product/'.$cart->id)}}">X</a></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>

<!-- Total -->
<div class="flex-w flex-sb-m p-t-26 p-b-30">
    @php
        $total = 0; 
        foreach($userCart as $cart) {
            $total += ($cart->price * $cart->quantity); 
        }
    @endphp
    <span class="m-text22 w-size19 w-full-sm">Total:</span>

    <span class="m-text21 w-size20 w-full-sm">{{ $total }}</span>
</div>
```

**ProductsController**

```php
public function addtocart(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $session_id = Session::get('session_id');
    if (empty($session_id)) {
        $session_id = str_random(40);
        Session::put('session_id', $session_id);
    }
    DB::table('cart')->insert(['product_id' => $data['product_id'], 'product_name' => $data['product_name'], 'product_code' => $data['product_code'], 'product_color' => $data['product_color'], 'price' => $data['price'], 'size' => $data['size'], 'quantity' => $data['quantity'], 'user_email' => $data['user_email'], 'session_id' => $session_id]);

    return redirect('cart')->with('flash_message_success', 'Product has been added in Cart!');
}

public function cart()
{
    $session_id = Session::get('session_id');
    $userCart = DB::table('cart')->where(['session_id' => $session_id])->get();
    foreach ($userCart as $key => $product) {
        $productDetails = Product::where('id', $product->product_id)->first();
        $userCart[$key]->image = $productDetails->image;
    }

    return view('products.cart')->with(compact('userCart'));
}
```

Comment: You are not showing the whole view, I bet that this part of code is within another loop that iterates over the `$cart` and shows details. So you will have to take it out of the main element, in order to be displayed once. And you can calculate the total within the other loop.

Comment: Calculate total price in controller. Make this outside of the view. It is the right way to do it.

Comment: @nakov updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the total in the controller since you already loop through the cart items there.

```
public function cart(){
    $session_id = Session::get('session_id');
    $userCart = DB::table('cart')->where(['session_id'=>$session_id])->get();
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($userCart as $key => $product) {
        $productDetails = Product::where('id',$product->product_id)->first();
        $userCart[$key]->image = $productDetails->image;
        $total += ($product->price * $product->quantity); 
    }
    return view('products.cart')->with(compact('userCart', 'total'));
}
```

And use the `$total` in your view.